# Easiest way to put password rules into AEM

Tags: aem

What is the most elegant way in AEM 6.0 to put a set of password rules in place into the admin interface?

We would need to restrict passwords to be at least 8 characters in length, with at least one number and one special character.

Would the best approach be to put a regex onto the user admin panels?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if AEM provides an interface which supports your query. The best approach would be to tackle this from ur OSGI bundles. Traditionally [chain of responsibility pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/chain_of_responsibility_pattern.htm) has been used to implement pwd rules, you can follow the same.